# How to render page in html via mail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I tried to have my own password reset confirmation mail template and it doesn't work in sense cause is rendering in .txt and not .html

I've tried with this view :

```
class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    @staticmethod
    def send_mail(subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email, to_email,
                  html_email_template_name=None):
        subject = render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body_text = render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
        body_html = render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body_text, from_email, [to_email])
        email_message.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')
        email_message.send()
```

and also the urls.py

```
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

and i've created a password_reset_email.html file in the registration folder in templates
But when i receive the mail is showing me the whole content in text, i can see the html tags...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the HTML content as the "main" content:

```
email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body_text, from_email, [to_email])
email_message.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')
email_message.content_subtype = 'html'
email_message.send()
```

Comment: It's not working, i mean i imported the msg from Tools.scripts.which.msg() cause i needed to import it

Comment: @Spikyd: sorry, `msg` should be `email_message` ... :(

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I changed msg with email_message and still doesn't work... :(

Comment: @Spikyd: what if you use `text/html` instead?

Comment: @Spikyd: it is possible that your email client is configured to prefer the text over HTML, since the email client can of course decide which to render.